# Cargar imágenes de un arreglo con Jquery

Tags: jquery, web

tengo un arreglo de imagenes que debo cargar en una división utilizando JQuery hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente.

```
var productos = new Array(
"afrodita.png",
"arpia.jpg",
"basilisco.jpg",
"caballo.jpg",
"centauro.jpg",
"fenix.jpg",
"gea.jpg",
"grifo.png",
"hidra.gif",
"kraken.jpg",
"medusa.png",
"minotauro.jpg",
"pegaso.jpg",
"poseidon.jpg",
"quimera.jpg",
"satiro.jpg",
"unicornio.jpg"
);
var t="";
window.onload=function(){
    //Cargar las imágenes en las divisiones
    $(".Brand").each(function(i,elemento){ 
                     function html () 
                      {$("img/minis/afrodita.png",this).css("width", "50px", "height", "50px")}
    });
```

Comment: Cual es el error que recibes?

Comment: Soy novato y no estoy seguro si esta bien. No se tampoco si debo repetir la misma función para cada imagen.... Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu ciclo each en tu arreglo productos tienes el `index` que es el indice o posicion del elemento que estas iterando mientras que `value` es el valor del elemento, en este caso particular el nombre de tu imagen. Con append, agregamos un elemento html tipo `img`.

```
$.each(productos, function( index, value ) {
     $( ".Brand" ).append( "<img src='"+this+"' > class='imagen'" );
});
```

Puedes crear una clase css llamada imagen POR EJEMPLO

```
.imagen{
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Gracias pero necesito utilizar . this .

Comment: @fabricio puedes reemplazar value por this y listo!

Comment: me lo imaginaba, muchas gracias.